# dyld: Library not loaded issue. Works on devices, but not on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, cocoapods

I know there are a number of posts about dyld library not loading. However, it seems the common thread is that it works on the simulator, but not on a device. I appear to be having the opposite problem. My app works just fine on a device, but gives the following error when run on a simulator (have tried iPhone 5, 6, 7, and SE)

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CR_APIKit.framework/CR_APIKit
 Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3069E359-20EF-4FCB-8565-F5ED29A5F76A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2C130BE7-9C2C-40AB-BA19-DDF28D601DD3/MyApp.app/MyApp
 Reason: image not found
```

CR_APIKit is a local pod spec containing some common code (PodSpec shown later).

I am running on Xcode 8 using Swift 3 targeting iOS 9 & 10. I am using CocoaPods 1.1.1. The simulator and the devices are all running iOS 10.

I have tried numerous solutions including:

- Setting Build Active Architectures Only to 'No' both in the CocoaPod and the app
- Setting Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries to YES
- Cleaning the project, removing the pods, updating the pods, restarting Xcode in various combinations
- Cleaning out the simulator by removing the device and running the simulator again with a fresh install
- Ensuring @executable_path/Frameworks is set in Runpath Search Paths

Of note, though, I have been able to get it to run on the simulator if I add the CR_APIKit.framework file under Target -> General -> Embedded Binaries. But, this just feels wrong as none of the third-party pods need this (Crashlytics, for instance, works just fine without needing its framework explicitly added).

Here is the Podfile for the app itself:

```
 source 'http://<local-podpec-repo>/podspecs.git'
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

 platform :ios, '9.0'
 use_frameworks!

 pod 'Fabric'
 pod 'Crashlytics'

 #local pods
 pod 'CR_APIKit'

 target 'MyApp' do
 end
```

And here is the pod spec for the local kit:

```
 Pod::Spec.new do |s|

    # ―――  Spec Metadata  ―――――――――――――――――――― #
    s.name         = "CR_APIKit"
    s.version      = "2.1.5"
    s.summary      = "description"
    s.homepage     = "http://<path to repo>/apikit.git"

    # ―――  Spec License  ―――――――――――――――――――― #
    s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }

     # ――― Author Metadata ――――――――――――――――――― #
     s.author             = { "me" => "me@me.com" }

     # ――― Platform Specifics ―――――――――――――――――― #
     s.platform     = :ios
     s.ios.deployment_target = "9.0"

     # ――― Source Location ――――――――――――――――― #
     s.source       = { :git => "http://<path to repo>/apikit.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }

     # ――― Source Code ――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
     s.source_files  = "APIKit"

     # ――― Project Linking ――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
     s.frameworks = "UIKIt", "CoreLocation"

     # ――― Project Settings ―――――――――――――――――――― #
     s.requires_arc = true

 end
```

It just seems odd that this works just fine on a device, but not on the simulator(s). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What architectures is CR_APIKit being built against? The Simulator architecture is different than your actual device architectures. What happens if you set Build Active Architectures to YES?

Comment: In various incarnations (as I have tried to solve the issue), the kit has been built with arm64, armv7, armv7s as well as a combo with those three plus x386 and x86_64; I have also tried those two combos both with active architectures set to yes and to no.